# LaTeX - Can only used only in preamble

Tags: latex

So I am working with LaTeXiT 2.10.1 and I am basically unable to use the service because everything I write seems to cause this same error:

> Can only be used in preamble

Below is my entire script:

```
------ PREAMBLE -------
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\begin{document}

------- END PREAMBLE ------
------ BODY --------

\title{Words}
\end{document}

---- END BODY -----
```

I don't understand why any kind of latex formatting is causing this.

If my body consists solely of text, it seems to work.

Comment: [TeX - LaTeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As the error says `\title` can only be used in preamble.